# Probability that a car accident is correctly attributed to faulty brakes

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

> The probability that a one-car accident is due to faulty brakes is 0.04, the probability that a one-car accident is correctly attributed to faulty brakes is 0.82, and the probability that a one-car accident is incorrectly attributed to faulty brakes is 0.03. What is the probability that (a) a one-car accident will be attributed to faulty brakes; (b) a one-car accident attributed to faulty brakes was actually due to faulty brakes?

Is my work below correct?

**My Approach:**

Event A- Car accident is due to faulty break

Event B- It gets correctly attributed to faulty break

Event D- It gets incorrectly attributed to faulty break

Event C- It gets attributed to faulty breaks ; then

P(A)=0.04

P(B)=0.82

P(D)=0.03

P(A')=0.96

(a) I use total probability rule i.e.

$P(C)=P(A)P(B|A)+P(A')P(D|A')$

$P(c)=(0.04)(0.82)+(0.96)(0.03)$

$P(C)=0.0328+0.0288$

$P(C)=0.0616$

(b) For this I used Bayes theorem;
$$P(A|C)=P(AnC)/P(C)=P(A)P(C|A)/P(C)\\
=(0.04)(0.82)/0.0616=0.0328/0.0616$$

$P(A|C)=0.532467532$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I have added my thoughts to this problem as you suggested and thank you for the suggestion . Do you know whether my approach is correct or not ?

Comment: Is event C meant to be it is incorrectly attributed to faulty brakes?

Comment: Choose a title which gives an idea what your question is about. The present title is meaningless.

Comment: How can $P(B)+P(B')$ not be equal to one?

Comment: @SuzuHirose I am sorry. I messed up there, it is a different event and I have corrected it now. Please look at it and give your thoughts. Thank you for making my text readable!

Comment: Your answer is correct

Comment: @Cathedral are you sure it's correct?

Comment: @SuzuHirose What error do you identify?

Comment: @Cathedral I'm writing an answer now.

Comment: 1. Your answer is perfectly correct *and* clear. $\quad$ 2. FYI, Questions on this site are intended to benefit future readers more than they are for just the Question-asker; please kindly accede to @PaulFrost's above request.

Comment: @ryang I will definitely try to do so as I am also from those people who have benefitted a lot from this site

Comment: @KingKong So have I. $\quad$ Thanks(to be clear, we mean the title of the *current* post)!

Comment: @ryang hahaha... I Know

Comment: @KingKong throwing every bit of subtlety out the window, they wish for you to change the title 'What should be the correct approach to solve this?' to something more informative about the question you asked. Perhaps something along the lines of 'Bayes Theorem in an exercise about faulty brakes' ?

Answer (score 3):

You've arrived at the correct answers, but the way you've phrased the problem is a muddle.

There are two circumstances, "attribution to faulty brakes" and "has faulty brakes". Let's call these events $A$ and $F$. Then you should write
$$
\begin{align}
P(F)&=0.04\\
P(A|F)&=0.82\\
P(A|F')&=0.03\\
\end{align}
$$
The things you're asked to calculate are:

#### (a) A one car accident will be attributed to faulty brakes

$$
\begin{align}
P(A)&=P(A|F)P(F)+P(A|F')P(F')\\
&=0.82\times0.04+0.03\times0.96\\
&=0.0616
\end{align}
$$
and

#### (b) a one-car accident attributed to faulty brakes was actually due to faulty brakes

$$
\begin{align}
P(F|A)&={P(A, F)\over P(A)} \\
&=
{P(A|F)\times P(F)\over P(A)}\\
&=
{0.04\times0.82\over0.0616}\\
&=0.532...\\
\end{align}
$$
You shouldn't have introduced all those other symbols, but somehow you made it all work.

Comment: While I do agree with the fact that many symbols were clumsily used, it did work out for them. (+1) for a well written answer with a clear thought process however!

Comment: @Cathedral it's quite impressive that OP got the right answers out of that.

Comment: [disappearing comment] The OP's presentation reads very coherently to me, so I'm struggling to understand how it is being perceived as clumsy or a muddle. Just my alternative perspective. @Cathedral

Comment: @ryang I suppose you could look at the edit history of the question?

Comment: Ah, now it make sense; thanks for pointing out! [disappearing]

Comment: The incredible disappearing ryang.

Comment: I *have* been donning my invisibility cloak lots, of late. $\quad$ Okay, I shall leave my above comments as they contextualise your Answer's opening line.